# Where to activate "Vector" Menu?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I am a QGIS newbie trying to work through Lex Berman's QGIS tutorial.  I'm stuck in the "join" unit, because I do not see a Vector menu on my menu bar.  The screen shots show that there should be a Vector menu after the Help menu and before the Window menu on the menu bar.

Is this a plugin I need to install, or did I install the software improperly?  (I've found that I've had to install a couple of plugins myself, things that aren't described outright in the tutorial.)

Comment: Would love to "accept" the answer, but the system won't let me login again as Caroline T. Schroeder, despite my having tried to login in every way imaginable and recover login info, etc. So please accept this as an "accept."

Comment: I merged your accounts, Carrie: you should now have full control over this thread and be able to accept the reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the "Vector" menu: Install and activate "**ftools**" plugin.

It should be installed and on by default if you use a recent version of QGIS though.

Comment: Thanks.  That did it.  I'm using 1.7.4, which I think is the latest version.  Almost none of the plugins are activated.